# How to get the object id after the button click in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working in MERN project.

**what I want**

*I am fetching the project list from the backend If i click on any project it should give the members list that is working on that project so i want to get the objectid of that clicked project*

**what i tried**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AdminDash = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [userData, setuserData] = useState([])
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const callAboutPage = async () => {
        try {

            const res = await fetch("/alldata", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                credentials: "include"
            })

            const data = await res.json()
            setuserData(data)
            console.log(setuserData);


            if (!res.status === 200) {
                const error = new Error(res.error)
                throw error
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            navigate("/")
        }
    }

    function handleButtonClick(id) {
        fetch(`/api/get-data/${id}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setData(data);
            console.log(data);
          });
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        callAboutPage()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10'>
                        <div class="row align-items-md-stretch">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="h-100 p-5 text-bg-light rounded-3">
                                    <h2>Current Ongoing Projects</h2>
                                    <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered mt-5">


                                        {
                                            userData.map((item, i) => (
                                                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                                                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                                        <NavLink onClick={() => handleButtonClick()} to="/admindash" className="text-decoration-none"><div class="fw-bold">{item.name}</div></NavLink>
                                                        Content for list item
                                                    </div>
                                                    <i class="bi bi-at"></i>
                                                </li>

                                            ))}




                                    </ol>
<label>{data.name}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AdminDash
```

**backend**

```
app.get('/api/get-data/:id', (req, res) => {
    ProjectSchema.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(doc);
      }
    });
  });
```

**the output i get in my console**

```
{stringValue: '"undefined"', valueType: 'string', kind: 'ObjectId', value: 'undefined', path: '_id', …}
```

**How to achieve this ..any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

In the mapping onClick pass item.id.
First make sure you getting it in your data while Fetching.

<NavLink onClick={() => handleButtonClick(item.id)} to="/admindash" className="text-decoration-none">{item.name}